Error 401 No Autorizado con la Autenticación JWT en una Aplicación de .NET 8 y Vue.js
Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación con usando net 8 para el backend y vue para el front.
De momento tengo el inicio de sesión. Una vez el usuario inicia sesión, cargan unos datos suyos en la pantalla "Home"
Estoy tratando de implementar un login con JWT para mayor seguridad y para aprender como hacerlo, ya que en aplicaciones más grandes es una buena práctica, pero me encuentro con el error 401 Unauthorized de manera permanente y no consigo resolverlo.
En mi archivo appsettings.json tengo los parámetros necesarios para el JWT
  "Jwt": {
    "Key": "8D9E3B5F7C2A4E9D1F3C6A7E9B2D4C8F",
    "Issuer": "http://localhost:5251",
    "Audience": "http://localhost:8080"
  }

Con esa clave firmo el token generado cuando el usuario inicia sesión:
// Método para iniciar sesión
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginDto loginDto)
{
  var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == 
  loginDto.UserName);
            
  if (user == null || !BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(loginDto.Password, user.Password))
  {
     return Unauthorized(new { message = "Invalid username or password." });
  }

  // Crear el token JWT
  var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
  var key = _configuration["Jwt:Key"];

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
  {
     throw new InvalidOperationException("JWT Key is not configured.");
  }

  var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
  var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
  {
     Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(
     [
         new(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
         new(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
     ]),
     Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
     SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature),
     Issuer = _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], 
     Audience = _configuration["Jwt:Audience"]
  };
  var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
  var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

  Console.WriteLine("Token: " + tokenString);
  Console.WriteLine("Issuer: " + _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"]);
  Console.WriteLine("Audience: " + _configuration["Jwt:Audience"]);

  return Ok(new { token = tokenString });
}

En el Almacenamiento Local veo que el token está guardado:

En la pestaña de Red veo que el token va en la solicitud y que en la respuesta me dice que no es válido.

He comprobado que el token generado es correcto en jwt.io y veo que son correctos el "Issuer" y el "Audience", además del identificador del usuario que estoy utilizando para hacer el login.
En el lado del cliente recojo de la respuesta el token generado en el servidor y lo meto en el local storage para tener acceso a él:
async handleSubmit() {
  try{
      const url = this.isRegistering 
      ? 'http://localhost:5251/auth/register' 
      : 'http://localhost:5251/auth/login'; 

      const response = await axios.post(url, { 
         username : this.username,
         password : this.password
      });

      if (this.isRegistering) {
          this.setMessage(response.data.message || "Registration successful! You can now log in.", false);
          this.clearFields(); 
      } else {
          const token = response.data.token;

          if(token) {
             localStorage.setItem('token', token)
             this.setMessage("Login successful!", false)
             this.login({ username: this.username })
             this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' });
          }
          else {
             this.setMessage('Login failed. Token not received', true);
          }

      }               
  } catch (error) {
      this.setMessage(error.response?.data?.message || "An error occurred. Please try again.", true);
       console.error('Error:', error.response.data);
  }
          
},

Una vez en la página de inicio, accedo a ese local storage desde el cliente para recoger el token y confirmar que el usuario que está ahora mismo logeado es el correcto:
methods: {
    async fetchTasks() {
      try {
        console.log("token", localStorage.getItem("token"));
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5251/api/task/upcoming', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
            },
        });
        this.tasks = response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching tasks:', error);
      }
    },
  },

Y este es el método del backend:
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TaskController(TaskManagerContext context) : ControllerBase
{
   private readonly TaskManagerContext _context = context;

   // Método para obtener las próximas 3 tareas para un usuario
   [HttpGet("upcoming")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetUpcomingTasks()
   {
      var userIdClaim = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
      if (userIdClaim == null)
      {
         return Unauthorized();
      }
      var userId = int.Parse(userIdClaim.Value);

      // Consulta las tareas para el usuario autenticado
      var upcomingTasks = await _context.Tasks
          .Where(t => t.UserId == userId)
          .OrderBy(t => t.Date)
          .Take(3)
          .ToListAsync();

      return Ok(upcomingTasks);
   }

}

Desde postman tengo el mismo problema.
En mi Program.cs tengo los servicios registrados en el orden en el que deben estar:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using backend.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using backend.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Database connection
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TaskManagerContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Add controllers support
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

//Apply CORS policy
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);

app.Run();

Por tanto, no se muy bien cómo proceder. He revisado varias veces que todo esté en orden y no veo nada raro. ¿Debería abandonar la idea de utilizar JWT porque no merece la pena en mi aplicación? Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.
